# What is the point of intersection between a parametric and a cartesian line?

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, linear-algebra

I have two staright lines.

One in parametric form:

```
L1 = {
  (x = x1 + t.a1),
  (y = y1 + t.b1),
  (z = z1 + t.c1)
}
```

And the other one is a cartesian line segment:

```
L2 = {
  (px1, py1, pz1),
  (px2, py2, pz2)
}
```

What's an efficient way to find the point of intersection of the two lines?

The method I can think of is:

- Convert L2 to parametric form
- Solve for a point P
- Find out if P lies on L2

However is there a more efficient way? This question is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-to-find-intersection-of-two-lines-in-3d. However I'm interested in efficiency rather than the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's **d1** is direction vector of the first line, **d2** is direction vector of whe second line, **bb** is the vector between base points (**bb=b2-b1**).

Let **p = (d1 x d2)** (vector product). If **p** is zero vector, then lines are parallel.

Then you need to check whether the lines do intersect: (**bb * p**) should be = 0 (scalar product). Else these lines are skew.

Intersection point is **i = b1 + d1 * [ (bb x d2) * p / (p * p) ]**

Comment: Thanks - I had considered this, but number of operations wise this is equally ineffective unless I'm using parallel computing for the matrix multiplications. In fact I have assembly dumps of both the solutions. The direction vector solution is more bulky (However I used the non-SSE BLAS for the second one which adds some overhead I guess).